# Java: How to call an integer value from an external method

Tags: java, methods, integer

I just started learning java so I'm sure I'm just missing something basic. I have to create a dice object with 7 sides which generates a random number between 1 and 7:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Dice {

      Random rand = new Random();
      int maxRoll = 7;

      public void roll(){
         int dicVal = rand.nextInt(maxRoll)+1; 
         }
  
   }
```

After that, I have to use another file to make 5 different dice from the original object, roll them, and detect weather or not they have rolled the same number.

```
public class DiceRollem {
   public static void main (String[] args) {

      int turn=0;
      
      while (turn < 10) {
         turn ++;
         
      Dice dice1;
      dice1 = new Dice();
      dice1.roll();
      
      Dice dice2;
      dice2 = new Dice();
      dice2.roll();
      
      Dice dice3;
      dice3 = new Dice();
      dice3.roll();
      
      Dice dice4;
      dice4 = new Dice();
      dice4.roll();
      
      Dice dice5;
      dice5 = new Dice();
      dice5.roll();
      }
   }
}
```

I am unsure exactly how to call the dicVal value from each of the dice in order to compare them. I was able to code something in the original file that would return the value, but there isn't supposed to be a return in the original, instead it should all be in the second file. Again, I'm sure this is something easy but after looking I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Create the dices outside of the loop also you have to return the value in your roll function for the comparison.

Comment: Store the value as a field on the `Dice` Object.  Currently the scope of the value is limited to the `roll` method

Comment: Have the roll() method return an int so that you can store it. I would also use an array of Dice objects rather than using individual variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a property, not a variable inside the method.

```
public class Dice {
   // Set as static final because it doesn't change and is common to all dices
   private static final int maxRoll = 7;   

   // dicVal as property, not as local variable
   private int dicVal;

   private Random rand = new Random();

   // Added to set up a random value just after construction
   public Dice() {
      roll();    
   }

   public void roll() {
      // roll method set the property now
      dicVal = rand.nextInt(maxRoll)+1; 
   }


   // The public method to get the value
   public int getValue() {
      return dicVal;
   }

}
```

And you can use it as follow:

```
 Dice dice1 = new Dice();
 System.out.println("The value is: " + dice1.getValue());
 dice1.roll(); // To change the value
 System.out.println("The new value is: " + dice1.getValue());
 ...
```

An enhancement could be create a dice declaring it's size on the constructor so you can have dices with 4, 6, 7 (or anything you like) sides.
Simply declare the maxRoll as a private field and set up it on the constructor as follow:

```
public class EnhancedDice {
   private int maxRoll = 7;   
   private int dicVal;

   private Random rand = new Random();

   public EnhancedDice(int maxRoll) {
      this.maxRoll = maxRoll;
      roll();    
   }

   public void roll() {
      dicVal = rand.nextInt(maxRoll) + 1; 
   }


   public int getValue() {
      return dicVal;
   }

}
```

And use it as follow:

```
 EnhancedDice diceWith7sides = new EnhancedDice(7);
 System.out.println("The value is: " + diceWith7sides.getValue());
 diceWith7sides.roll(); // To change the value
 System.out.println("The new value is: " + diceWith7sides.getValue());
 ...
 EnhancedDice diceWith6sides = new EnhancedDice(6);
 System.out.println("The value is: " + diceWith6sides.getValue());
 diceWith6sides.roll(); // To change the value
 System.out.println("The new value is: " + diceWith6sides.getValue());
 ...
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat no, if you would like to roll your dice and not create an immutable not useful dice. Check the updated answer that explain how to roll the dice to change its value

Answer (score -1):

## tl;dr

You are creating new dice on each turn. Don't. In the real world we are modeling, dice are not discarded after each roll. The same physical dice are re-used for multiple rolls. So your `new Dice()` should *not* be inside your `while (turn < 10) {…}`.

- Establish a collection of dice when starting the game.
- On each turn, run through the collection of dice, asking each die to roll itself.
- Each die should remember the result of its roll. **Your code is missing this feature.** As your `roll` method ends, the `int dicVal` vaporizes, poof ☁, gone. You should add a member field on that class to remember `dicVal`.
- After each roll, ask each die for its result.

You asked:

> how to call the dicVal value from each of the dice

First store the result as the value of a member field on the class. To later access that value, directly access the member field. To prevent others from altering that value, you may want to make the member field  `private`, while adding a getter method to return its value.

## Details

Generally in object-oriented programming, we want each object to take care of itself, and keep to itself.

Regarding "take care of itself", each die should keep track of its current state, that is, which face is showing. In the example code below, the `Die` class carries a member field `pips` for the number of dots/marks currently shown on its displayed face.

And the class also holds a member field for the number of faces on that particular die, which is 7 in your example. Notice that this field is marked `final` as it does not change. In contrast, the `pips` field changes on every roll of that die.

Regarding "keep to itself", the job of a die is know its current state (pips) and to roll (change its state, for a new number of pips). It is *not* the job of the die to get involved in managing the larger game in which it is a part. The game should keep track of each die; each die should know nothing about the game. The game's job is to (a) ask each die to roll itself, and (b) interrogate each die for its current state (pips).

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Die
{
    final private int faces; // How many faces (sides) does this die have.
    private int pips; // Number of pips (dots, marks) on the currently shown face.
    final private UUID id;

    public Die ( int faces )
    {
        this.faces = faces;
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.roll();
    }

    // Logic
    public void roll ( )
    {
        this.pips = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , this.faces + 1 );
    }

    // Getters
    public int getPips ( )
    {
        return this.pips;
    }

    // Object methods


    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Die{ " +
                "faces=" + faces +
                " | pips=" + pips +
                " | id=" + id +
                " }";
    }
}
```

The other class, `Game`, calls the `roll` method on that die. The die then internally generates the random number for the new number of pips displayed. The `Game` object does this for each of its collected `Die` objects. The `Game` object can ask each `Die` object for its current state, its current number of pips.

You asked:

> I am unsure exactly how to call the dicVal value from each of the dice in order to compare them

Your code has a problem there. You assigned the result, the new number of pips, to a local variable named `dicVal`. But then your method ended. When that methods ends, **all local variables including `dicVal` fall out of scope**. That means that (a) any local primitive values such as an `int` are instantly gone, and (b) any local object references such as `Integer` are dropped which leaves the object to become a candidate for eventual garbage-collection (if no other references to that same object exist). So the moment after determining the new face value of the die, you discard that number.

You need to assign the result of the roll to some place that lasts longer. The ideal place is a member field on that same class. Notice in the code example above that we do just that. The result of rolling each die is stored within that `Die` object on its private `pips` field of type `int`.

It is the job of the `Game` object to first collect all the dice, and then inspect each one. The [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) part is another part that you are missing. Notice in the example below how the `Game` object holds a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of `Die` objects. We populate that list in the constructor of the `Game`. The `Game` object can loop the `Die` objects in that list, interrogating each for its current state by calling `getPips`.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Game
{
    private List < Die > dice;

    public Game ( )
    {
        // Setup the game. Collect some dice to play.
        int countFacesOnEachDie = 7;
        int countDice = 5;
        this.dice = new ArrayList <>( countDice );
        for ( int nthDie = 1 ; nthDie <= countDice ; nthDie++ )
        {
            this.dice.add( new Die( countFacesOnEachDie ) );
        }
    }

    // Logic
    public void rollDice ( )
    {
        for ( Die die : dice )
        {
            die.roll();
        }
    }

    public String report ( )
    {
        int total = 0;
        for ( Die die : dice )
        {
            total = total + die.getPips();
        }
        String listing = this.dice.toString();
        String message = "Total: " + total + " = Dice: " + listing;
        return message;
    }

    // Main method (the app). Could be located in another class, such as `App` or `Main` is is likely in real work.
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        int countTurns = 9;
        for ( int nthTurn = 1 ; nthTurn <= countTurns ; nthTurn++ )
        {
            game.rollDice();
            System.out.println( "Turn # " + nthTurn + " ➡ " + game.report() );
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Turn # 1 ➡ Total: 17 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=1 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=3 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=1 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
Turn # 2 ➡ Total: 22 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=5 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=3 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=2 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
Turn # 3 ➡ Total: 30 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=5 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=5 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
Turn # 4 ➡ Total: 22 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=2 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=4 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=4 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=5 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
Turn # 5 ➡ Total: 16 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=2 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=5 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=1 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=2 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
Turn # 6 ➡ Total: 27 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=4 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=4 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
Turn # 7 ➡ Total: 13 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=1 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=3 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=1 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=1 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
Turn # 8 ➡ Total: 27 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=5 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=3 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=5 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
Turn # 9 ➡ Total: 24 = Dice: [Die{ faces=7 | pips=2 | id=37c5c2ea-52d7-4e1f-a92c-7b99e0e7b70c }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=2 | id=58a724e6-a1a5-43d9-bc00-808c15a1980e }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=db5557a5-8805-4f50-84a4-5d11eb1ec95a }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=6 | id=a61e5741-c56f-44d3-8222-073898da60bb }, Die{ faces=7 | pips=7 | id=0e96c3b6-5186-4323-bb26-dcfe99093a02 }]
```

Tip: Notice how I carefully chose names for each class and method. I used the singular `Die` for the class that represents each individual piece. I used the plural `dice` as the name for a collection `Die` objects. I named the current number shown on each die as `pips` rather than `dicVal`, the correct lingo according to Wikipedia. I chose `Game` rather than `DiceRollem` for the outer class that makes use of `Die` objects.  Focusing on such names can help you to clarify your design. If all the names seem to work together smoothly, that may be a sign of a good design. If the names seem clunky or clash, or lack a clear specific meaning, that may be a sign of a poor design.